# HDR format in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, hdr

When HDR is enabled, Windows 10 advanced display setting shows it is 12 bit HDR, but the TV shows the source is HDR10. It is strange that Windows output HDR12 when the TV only display HDR10.

Does Windows 10 have a standard fixed frame buffer HDR pixel format? Or is it fixed but depend on the GPU? Or is there a way to set the frame buffer HDR pixel format and the output HDR format (if it can be set to different than frame buffer HDR pixel format)

Comment: “It is strange that Windows output HDR12 when the TV only display HDR10.” HDR support is all over the place in the TV sector.  Samsung has their own standard.  While others support HDR and HDR+ while others also support Dolby Vision.  What TV manufacturer? What GPU?

Comment: </rant> It's not just that the spec is all over the place, the entire structure is based on guesswork; artificially sharpening edges that were never meant to be sharp, ruining the contrast in some vain attempt to show you some artificially inflated gamut. It looks bl**dy atrocious. Switch it off & watch what the Director of Photography spent millions of dollars getting right for you, not what some TV algorithm decides what's best. </rant> ...Qualification: I work in the TV/film industry:P